# json serialize issue: unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm attempting to take a basic serializable object that's held within a seriazable dictionary and pass it to a javascript function that will generate a modal with that information. The object has a few string variables, nothing complicated.

Here's the object I'm passing in:

```
[Serializable]
public class Details
{
    public Details() {}

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I set the strings to their appropriate values, and then attempt to create a link that calls a javascript modal (the ID is calling the appropriate:

```
protected string WriteDetailsLink(object ID)
{
    string results = "";

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    results += "showDetailsModal(" + jss.Serialize(dictionaryList[ID.ToString()]) + "); return false;";

    return results;
}
```

And the html link itself on the aspx page:

```
<a id='detailsDialog' onclick="<%# WriteDetailsLink( Eval( "ID" )) %>">Details</a>
```

And the javascript function for the modal, currently displaying nothing:

```
function showDetailsModal(Details) {



    $('#DetailsModal_dialog').dialog(
    {
        modal: true,
        //height: 500,
        width: 600,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        open: function () {

        },
        close: function(event, ui) {}

    });
}
```

Everything works fine, the ID gets passed along and when I inspect the link after running it looks like this:

```
<a id='detailsDialog' onclick="showDetailsModal({"ID":"40662463","Name":"72485-3"}); return false;">Details</a>
```

I've got a div setup for the modal and I'm attempting to parse out the name to insert into it, here's the new function

```
function showBatchDetailsModal(groupDetails) {

    var tmpData = jQuery.parseJSON(groupDetails);

    $('#DetailsModal_dialog').dialog(
    {
        modal: true,
        //height: 500,
        width: 600,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        open: function () {
            $('#detailsName').text(tmpData.Name);
        },
        close: function(event, ui) {}

    });
}
```

I'm getting

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o " in jquery.min.js

Same happens for $('#detailsName').val(tmpData.Name); and .value.

Comment: The value passed to the function is already an object, not a string containing JSON, so you cannot parse it. Just remove that line ( and fix variable names ).

Comment: Why are you using `parseJSON` to parse what is already an object? It's only JSON data if it arrives as a string that represents your data structure.

Comment: I'm going off pre-existing code, still pretty fresh JSON. Now that I see what I did wrong it makes a ton more sense to me. It's weird though, similar code exists elsewhere in the project and wasn't acting up. In any case, thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse('{"ID":"40662463","Name":"72485-3"}');
```

then if you just put `jsonObj.ID` you get the value 40662463.

You can test this just in the console of chrome using inspect element. You are missing the 
`'  '` that i put inside the parse function

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be he following

```
function showBatchDetailsModal(groupDetails) {

    var tmpData = groupDetails; // jQuery.parseJSON(groupDetails);
    //Don't need to parse it into json. as its already parsed.

    $('#DetailsModal_dialog').dialog(
    {
        modal: true,
        //height: 500,
        width: 600,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        open: function () {
            $('#detailsName').val(tmpData.BatchName); //<--- .text(...) is changed to .val(...)
            //If val(...) doesn't work use .text(...)
        },
        close: function(event, ui) {}

    });
}
```